# php max_execution_time 30 seconds, but ran a script for 2 hours

Tags: php

I ran a script for 2 hours via the command line. The script ran on Mac OS X and queries the database for a list of job and generates a pdf and sends an e-mail over and over again. It keep going and didn't fail. The script ran from the command line. I thought it only had 30 seconds.

Comment: And? By default, CLI execution time is unlimited, not 30 seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**PHP CLI vs. PHP CGI**](http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-cgi.shtml)

> max_execution_time: CLI default is 0 (unlimited)

(for the record: CLI - command line interface)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set ,ax time execution in your script.

```
void set_time_limit (int $seconds)
```

Note that this work only when safe mode off.

> This function has no effect when PHP
>   is running in safe mode. There is no
>   workaround other than turning off safe
>   mode or changing the time limit in the
>   php.ini.